# MapView not displaying properly

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, xcode5, mapkit

I have a MapView in my Navigation Controller that has a textFeild and button that was being built properly. But all of a sudden, when I build on the 7.1 simulator the mapView is taking up the entire viewController. All three objects are properties that are outlets properly connected to the viewController. I have the position of the mapView on the view set in viewDidLoad as:

```
self.mapView.frame =      CGRectMake(0, 110, 320, 500);
self.textField.frame    = CGRectMake(10, 10, 230, 30);
self.searchButton.frame = CGRectMake(250, 10, 70, 30);
```

Even when I add remove from superview to viewdidload,

```
[self.mapView removeFromSuperview];
```

the mapView still builds. I even put breakpoints to see if the lines of code were skipped over and they weren't. It seems like xcode is caching my xcode(5.1.1) somehow. Is there anything that I can do to stop getting this issue? The mapView drawing isn't being called anywhere else in the viewController.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting all files in the DerivedData folder(~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData) fixed this issue.